# What is another way to say "This is because"

Tags: synonyms

Adaptations are a strong reason to why the study of Shakespearian Texts is a key element in the Australian curriculum. This is because, when reading the scripted version in a book, teenagers become uninterested and don’t ‘pay attention’ to what they are reading.

Comment: That should be 'reason why' or 'reason as to why'. Is there a reason why you wish to find an alternative for the totally idiomatic  'This is because' here? Is there one for the scare-quotes round 'pay attention', again totally idiomatic?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 'this is because' is, like 'due to the fact that', something that English teachers like to tell students not to do, because they are inarticulate or verbose or something. I have no idea what the alternatives are.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to replace it with "for".

[From M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for):

> **for**
>
> *conjunction*
>
> :  for the reason that :  on this ground :  *because*
>
> the bill should be listed as paid, **for** I mailed it in on time

Comment: Agreed.  "reason . . why"  is a tautology. "Reason why  . . is because" is a double tautology.   "reason to . ." requires a following verb, eg "reason to believe". Agree also that no quotes are appropriate for 'pay attention'.